# VBA: Managing Dictionaries with arrays for "value"

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am trying to keep track of data over time (6 weeks), so I am storing the data into a excel sheet with the following format:

```
name  week1  week2  week3  week4  week5  week6
name1 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
.
.
```

I then read the data into an excel dictionary in the following manner:

```
Dim set1 As Dictionary      ' set from datasheet
Set set1 = New Dictionary
Dim dsLastRow As Integer
dsLastRow = lastRowInSheet(sheet)
For i = 2 To dsLastRow
            set1.Add Cells(i, 1), Array(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 7))
Next i
```

I also take the current values from the current report (the most current week and set that into its own collection -- the overall attempt is to cross validate the data)

```
col_num = ColNumFromName(sheet, "Station")
Dim set2 As Dictionary      ' set from recent Report
Set set2 = New Dictionary
For i = 5 To lastRow
            set2.Add Cells(i, col_num), Cells(i, lastColNum)
Next i
```

**My question is, how do I access the individual values in set1 where an "item" is an array of values?** Please look below for clarification

```
' cross validate the stations
        For Each key1 In set1.Keys()
            Dim removeKey As Boolean
            removeKey = True
            For Each key2 In set2.Keys()
                If StrComp(key1, key2) = 0 Then
                    Dim usageVals() As String
                    Debug.Print set1(key1) '' FAILS HERE with "type MISMATCH
                    Debug.Print usageVals(2)
                    usageVals = set1.Item(key1) "" "" 
                    usageVals(1) = usageVals(2)
                    usageVals(2) = usageVals(3)
                    usageVals(3) = usageVals(4)
                    usageVals(4) = usageVals(5)
                    usageVals(5) = usageVals(6)
                    usageVals(6) = set2.Item(key1)
                    set1.Item(key1) = usageVals
                    removeKey = False
                End If
                Next
                If removeKey Then ' take eNB out of datasheet since it didnt appear in newest report
                    set1.Remove key1
                End If
        Next
        . 
        .
```

Can someone explain how I should access the individual values? I have tried also set1.Item(key1) too.

Comment: Im wondering if its because of the string type of usageVals()

Comment: You can't `Debug.Print set1(key1)` because `set1(key1)` is an array: `set1.Add Cells(i, 1), Array(...)` - you added `Cells(i, 1)` as the key and an array of cells as the value. This also means the values in `Cells(i, 1)` must be unique, otherwise `.Add` will start throwing "key already exists" errors. As for `set1.Item(key1)`, it's exactly the same as `set1(key1)` - `.Item` just happens to be the *default property* of the collection type (here a `Dictionary`)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ok, I understand that. But I'm still confused about why I cant do usageVals = set1(key1) they are both just arrays..

Comment: Try with a variant array, or just a variant.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you that helped. I should have went with that instinct. Ha.